# ¿Como obtener un campo de un array con el id de otro array?

Tags: phalcon

Tengo 2 array de los cuales necesito traer un campo del segundo array y concatenarlo al primer array.

```
"data": [
        {
            "idclv_propiedad": "1",
            "id_opera": "ZHSP",
            "es_propiedad": "1",
            "idclv_marca": "2",
            "estado": "1",
            "fecha_creacion": "2018-03-20 16:10:27",
            "usuario_creacion": "sherrera",
            "usuario_ultima_modificacion": "gadrian",
            "fecha_ultima_modificacion": "2020-01-16 16:13:10"
        },
        {
            "idclv_propiedad": "2",
            "id_opera": "ZMGR",
            "es_propiedad": "1",
            "idclv_marca": "1",
            "estado": "1",
            "fecha_creacion": "2018-03-20 16:10:27",
            "usuario_creacion": "sherrera",
            "usuario_ultima_modificacion": "sherrera",
            "fecha_ultima_modificacion": "2018-03-20 16:10:27"
        }
],
```

el segundo:

```
"marca": [
        {
            "idclv_marca": "1",
            "marca": "slice",
            "estado": "1",
            "fecha_creacion": "2020-01-14",
            "usuario_creacion": "lugomez",
            "usuario_ultima_modificacion": "",
            "fecha_ultima_modificacion": "0000-00-00"
        },
        {
            "idclv_marca": "2",
            "marca": "price",
            "estado": "1",
            "fecha_creacion": "2020-01-14",
            "usuario_creacion": "lugomez",
            "usuario_ultima_modificacion": "",
            "fecha_ultima_modificacion": "0000-00-00"
        }
    ],
```

Lo que quiero hacer es que a partir de el campo "idclv_marca" que esta en el primer array obtener el campo "marca" del segundo array y posteriormente concatenarlo en el primer array de tan manera que la salida sea el primer array mas el campo marca del segundo array.

tengo lo siguiente pero no funciona ya que solo trae el primer registro que encuentra y no para cada uno de los elementos en el array

```
foreach ($data as $key => $item){

            $key = array_search($item['idclv_marca'], array_column($modelmarca, 'idclv_marca'));
            if($key){
                $array = $modelmarca[$key]['marca'];
                $item['marca'] = $array;
            }
        }
```

agradeceria su ayuda y quedo a sus ordenes para cualquier cosa.
saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por lo que describes, creo que buscas algo así:

```
foreach($data as $i=>$d)
    foreach($modelmarca as $j=>$e)
        if($d['idclv_marca']==$e['idclv_marca'])
            $data[$i]['marca']=$e['marca'];
```

Obteniendo:

> ```
> Array
> (
>     [0] => Array
>         (
>             [idclv_propiedad] => 1
>             [id_opera] => ZHSP
>             [es_propiedad] => 1
>             [idclv_marca] => 2
>             [estado] => 1
>             [fecha_creacion] => 2018-03-20 16:10:27
>             [usuario_creacion] => sherrera
>             [usuario_ultima_modificacion] => gadrian
>             [fecha_ultima_modificacion] => 2020-01-16 16:13:10
>             [marca] => price
>         )
>
>     [1] => Array
>         (
>             [idclv_propiedad] => 2
>             [id_opera] => ZMGR
>             [es_propiedad] => 1
>             [idclv_marca] => 1
>             [estado] => 1
>             [fecha_creacion] => 2018-03-20 16:10:27
>             [usuario_creacion] => sherrera
>             [usuario_ultima_modificacion] => sherrera
>             [fecha_ultima_modificacion] => 2018-03-20 16:10:27
>             [marca] => slice
>         )
>
> )
> ```

Por favor, confírmame si he entendido correctamente tu problema y hazme saber cualquier duda que tengas para explicar la respuesta lo mejor posible.